# c#, how do i create this menu in windows form application(attached image)

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmBZj.jpg)

I would like this kind of menu for my project. where can i find it in the form designer for windows form?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Did not notice typo in title

Comment: Looks like a tab control to me

Comment: Use the `menuStrip`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in Visual Studio:

[image]

To add events to your menu items just double click on the entries in the menu to open up an event block for you to enter code.